# ¿Porqué funcionan las funciones recursivas de tipo void?

Tags: c++, funciones, recursión

**Tengo** una **duda**: ¿Porqué las **funciones** **recursivas** de tipo void **funcionan**?

Tal vez no me **entiendas**... Mira este **ejemplo**:

```
void contar(int n){
    if(n == 0){
        return;
    }else{
        cout<<"Contando: "<<n<<endl;
        contar(n-1);
        cout<<"Como rayos he llegado aqui?"<<endl;
    }
}
```

**He depurado esa función en Dev-C++** y no **entiendo** como se **imprime** "Como rayos he llegado aqui?" si se está llamando a la **función** **recursiva** contar(n-1), hasta que **finalice** su **recursividad**... Sí alguien pudiera explicarme como funciona esa función se lo **agradecería mucho**.

Comment: Cuando finaliza la recursividad de `contar() ` regresa a la función que la llamó y se sigue ejecutando el programa desde ahí, en tu caso imprime ese mensaje.

Comment: @Lobos Ok, muchas gracias. Pero, ¿porqué se imprime varias veces "Como rayos he llegado aqui? 

Mira lo que sale:

Contando: 6
Contando: 5
Contando: 4
Contando: 3
Contando: 2
Contando: 1
Como rayos he llegado aqui?
Como rayos he llegado aqui?
Como rayos he llegado aqui?
Como rayos he llegado aqui?
Como rayos he llegado aqui?
Como rayos he llegado aqui?

--------------------------------
Process exited with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hagamos una depuración a una llamada recursiva a `contar()` pasándole el número 2.

```
void main(){

 contar(2);

}
```

En el método `main()` se hace la primera llamada a `contar()`, llamemosle `contar0()`.

Dentro de `contar0()` se evalúa si `n == 0`, como `n == 2` entonces se imprime el mensaje `Contando` y se llama nuevamente a `contar(n - 1)` de forma recursiva, llamemosle `contar1()`.

Dentro de `contar1()` se evalúa si `n == 0`, como `n == 1` entonces se imprime el mensaje `Contando` y se llama nuevamente a `contar(n - 1)`, llamemosle `contar2()`.

Dentro de `contar2()` se evalúa si `n == 0`, como `n == 0` entonces se retorna, termina la recursividad.

Volvemos de nuevo a `contar1()`, justo a la línea donde se llamó a `contar2()`, y ahí el programa se sigue ejecutando e imprime la línea `como rayos llegué aquí?`. Continúa la ejecución y retorna a la función donde fue llamada, en este caso `contar0()`.

En `contar0()` se continúa la ejecución después de llamar a `contar1()` y nuevamente se imprime el mensaje `como rayos llegué aquí?`, continúa la ejecución y retorna, esta vez al método `main()`.

Comment: Gracias, por fin, me quedó claro, gracias. Solo ahora me faltará entender las funciones recursivas con más de 1 parámetro y además las funciones recursivas que no sean de tipo void.